# How to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

In $K[x]_3$,Define linear transformation:$\sigma(f(x))=xf'(x)-f(x)$.Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\sigma$.
I want to let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d.$then $f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$.So $xf'(x)-f(x)=2ax^3+bx^2-d$.But next I don't know how to go on.Thanks.

Comment: Consider the action of $\sigma$ on a basis of your space and you quickly see some eigenvectors: $\sigma(1) = -1$, $\sigma(x) = 0$, $\sigma(x^2)=x^2$, $\sigma(x^3) = 2x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalue means to find $\lambda$ from equation $\sigma(f)=\lambda f$. Plug in your result,
$$2ax^3+bx^2-d=\lambda(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$$
Compare coefficients, you get

$$2a=\lambda a,~~b=\lambda b,~~0=\lambda c,~~-d=\lambda d$$

Next, you need to discuss $a,b,c,d,\lambda$. For example, one eigenvalue is $\lambda_1=0$, in this case, you get $a=b=d=0$, and $c$ might not be zero. Therefore you get the eigenvector $f_1=x$. Similarly, you can find other non-zero eigenvalues and their eigenvectors.

Can you proceed from here?